# How to secure a contact form against spamming which is processed by AWS Lambda and API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda, API Gateway and SES to process a contact form. Is there any recommendation how to secure the contact form against spamming?

Thank you.

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are referring to bot spam, consider using a good ol' CAPTCHA:

> Protect your website from spam and abuse while letting real people
>   pass through with ease

[NoCAPTCHA reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)

This is Googles new version of reCAPTCHA. noCAPTCHA reCAPTCHA is the result, and it makes it easier to prove you’re users are real humans, without having to  type in the classic distorted text image.

This version simply offers a checkbox that says “I’m not a robot.” When you check the box, it performs a number of tests using a “risk analysis engine” to determine if you’re human or not.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How does this protect API gateway exactly? because the abuser can use the system manually once to see the network request and then he can directly use the network request without visiting the frontend.

Comment: Use `honeypot`, `ratelimiter`, put rate limiters on APIs through middleware for an instance, signup API can be called X times in a day with X.X.X.X IP Address & AWS does offer free DDoS protection on all services so after all these your APIs will be pretty much secure, in the end it's never ending process.